# How to get json data from wiki api?

Tags: android, json, wikipedia-api

Does anyone have any idea how to use
wikipedia Api for getting some basic json data base on search keyword like:
the Title , some short content or summary ,page url and the most important thing is the image.
I tried to use wiki api sandbox but i can't understand how to use it and set it like i want.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=query&list=search&format=json&srsearch=dog&srnamespace=4&srprop=snippet&srlimit=15&generator=allimages

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple, Here is a test example:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&titles=donald%20Trump&format=json

read the docs

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aProperties#revisions_.2F_rv

Comment: But where is the images?

Comment: I want all in one json. There is a way to get that?

Comment: @meda Somthing like:
Title:"dog"
summary:"blah blah...."
imageUrl:"www.wiki.com\bllb\kbkbk\dog.jpg"

Comment: @Anna https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=dog&prop=pageimages&pithumbsize=300

Comment: @meda I'm really appreciate your help but i think you are not understand me.
I know how to get all the data separately..But I want it on one json

Comment: you cannot do it all at once sorry

Comment: Ok, there is way to get the data by page id?

Comment: Or to get images by wiki url page is would be better :)

Comment: I dont thing the pages have Id, why dont you run 2 requests